# Widget stops working atfter I close my app

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a widget from my app that initially makes a POST request and gets some info in an array and displays them on the widget. It has two buttons for going next and previous on this information and it works perfectly when i build the App.

Problem is the moment i close the app the widget stops working, the buttons do nothing.

I have no idea what to do.

As long as i keep my app opened the app works perfectly but i want it to work even when the app is closed. How can I do that ?

Comment: I'm confused ... "As long as i keep my **app** opened the **app** works perfectly but i want it to work even when the **app** is closed". I guess you wanted to write you want the widget to work. Does the widget have dependencies to any Activity? If so, what are these?

Comment: No it doest have any dependencies, it has 2 buttons to change the text in it and thats it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Service running in background that communicates with the AppWidgetProvider. See this example: [Widget-Service communication](http://rxwen.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/communication-between-android-widget.html)

Comment: Look I have a JSONArray and an ArrayList that I need for the widget, but when i close the app they become null. How can I keep them from becoming null ?